# Google Pass Tab didn't show on Google Pay App on iPhone

Tags: android, ios, iphone, google-pay

I have some Google Passes associated with my google account, and I can see them in Google Pay app on my Android phone. However, they are not showing on the Google Pay app on the iPhone.

On my Android phone, there are 4 tabs on the bottom: **Home, Payment, Passes, Send;**

On my iPhone, there are only 2 tabs: **Home, Payment methods.**

Is this a limitation of Google Pay for iPhone? Or something is wrong with the Pass/setting?

[image: Google Pay on Android and iPhone]

Answer (score 0):

Actually Google Pay on iPhone support only the transfers between friends. Apple Wallet is equivalent on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Google Pay on IPhone was updated to support passes.